# subir alteração para o repositorio no github

Tags: git, github

sou iniciante na programação, estou fazendo um projeto com uma pessoa e precisei clonar um repositorio dela no github e fazer algumas alteraçoes, como faço para enviar as alterações para o github dela de volta? 
ps.: de preferência em uma nova branch

Answer (score 1):

Caso queira adicionar todos os arquivos alterados utilize o comando:

```
git add .
```

Caso queira adicionar apenas um arquivo específico:

```
git add NOME_DO_ARQUIVO.EXTENSAO
```

Para criar uma nova branch execute os seguintes comandos:

```
git checkout -b NOME_DA_BRANCH
```

Commite as alterações com o comando:

```
git commit -m "MENSAGEM DO COMMIT"
```

Envie as alterações para o repositório com o comando:

```
git push origin NOME_DA_BRANCH
```

Answer (score 1):

Cria uma nova branch com:

```
git branch <nome>
```

Agora é só fazer o commit das alteração e enviar para o repositório:

**Commit:**

```
git add .
```

O git add adiciona os arquivos para realizar o commit. A utilização do ponto(.) é para adicionar todos os arquivos que foram modificados. Você consegue ver os arquivos alterados e adicionados para commit com `git status`

```
git commit -m "<mensagem>"
```

**Repositório remoto**

Você consegue verificar o nome do repositório remoto com `git remote` e se o caminho com `git remote get-url <nome-repositorio-remoto>`

Feito isso é só utilizar o comando para empurrar suas alterações locais para o repositório remoto(github):

```
git push <nome-repositorio-remoto> <nome-branch>
```

Comment: mas quando faço isso ta aparacendo que vai subir para o meu github. Tem alguma forma de mudar e enviar direto para uma branch nova no repositório dele?

Comment: Você cria uma branch local na sua maquina e quando vc der push ele cria a branch no repositorio remoto que você está conectado! Ah e não esqueça de agradecer quem te ajudou ai...

Comment: Você fez um fork do repositório do seu amigo?

Comment: fiz não, só fiz o clone mesmo

Comment: Se você ja fez o commit ele ficará no seu repositório local, ai para você enviar para o repositorio do seu amigo no github você tem que rodar esse comando: git push <nome-repositorio-remoto> <nome-branch>

Comment: ah sim, entendi, obg!